# Empty ng-model overwrites ng-value

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ngmodel

when I use ng-model together ng-value. ng-value returns empty even there is a value given. 
for example, there are two controllers called FirstCtrl and SecondCtrl.
This is FirstCtrl, and If I type a value for this input, it will write in my SeconCtrl input since I call ng-value="firstname" in my SecondController:

I can pass the value from firstctrl to secondctrl(I mean first input field to second input field). But the second input field has an ng-model called d_firstname, which doesn't allow to save ng-value but ng-value is displaying the correct value but saves empty because of ng-model(d_firstname). However, i need d_firstname if user wants to enter new value. Moreover, If I type over the input field in the secondCtrl, I can save the record because of d_firstname but if I keep not modifying anything in that input field, returns empty. hope you get the problem. Please someone help on this.. I wanted to pass data from one form to other if checkbox clicked for billing details and shopping details are same

FirstController input:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" required>
```

SecondCtrl input:

```
<input name="firstname" ng-value="firstname" ng-model="d_firstname">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in using `ng-value` and `ng-model` together.

You could use `ng-change` event to update the second one

```
<input name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" ng-change="updateName()" required>
<input name="d_firstname" ng-model="d_firstname">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.updateName = function(){
    $scope.d_firstname = $scope.firstname
}
```

Note that you should always use an object in `ng-model`. You will run into problems with child scopes if you don't

Comment: but I want to pass the text from first input to second input, if they want to modify they can type. how can I do that without ng-value?

Comment: they can type in second one and it will not affect the first

Comment: No I mean. You type 'cat' for instance in first input and automatically it should be displayed in the second input field. if user wants to modify, he will change. How to do that? because with ng-value I can pass that value but when I use ng-model also in second input, it gives empty value when saves, but it displays in the second input field.

Comment: Try using an object in ng-model. That is a golden and very important rule. It's quite possible you are having child scope issues using primitive binding.

Comment: can you tell one thing? . is it possible to display a value typed in first input to second input automatically using ng-change? like ng-value. Please tell that

Comment: yeah, by the way that controller code you wrote would come inside first or second controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125411/discussion-between-abel-anojan-sithamparappillai-and-charlietfl).

Comment: are these nested controllers? I overlooked there were 2 controllers

Comment: no separate two controlloers. I am passing like this:
FirstCtrl:
 $scope.$watch('firstname', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue)
                    Data.setFirstName(newValue);
            });
Second: 
 $scope.$watch(function () {
                return Data.getFirstName();
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue)
                    $scope.firstname = newValue;
            });

Comment: you wouldn't need the second watch if you were using an object for `ng-model` and therefore storing as object in service. Create a simple plunker demo with a simple service and 2 controllers